# I inserted a jquery slider in magento (flexslider) but it wont load

Tags: jquery, html, slider, magento-1.7, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to load a slider called flexslider but its not working and i can't figure it out.

It has something to do with a line in magento local.xml:

```
 <!-- Add js/css globally --> <reference name="head">
```

Any help please?
http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

The console shows this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'flexslider' of null"

The specific section is this one:

```
<div class="std"><script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
 animation: "slide"
  });
});
</script>
<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li><img src="http://127.0.0.1/magento/skin/frontend/waterlee-boilerplate/default/images/kitchen1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="http://127.0.0.1/magento/skin/frontend/waterlee-boilerplate/default/images/kitchen2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="http://127.0.0.1/magento/skin/frontend/waterlee-boilerplate/default/images/kitchen3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="http://127.0.0.1/magento/skin/frontend/waterlee-boilerplate/default/images/kitchen4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this code within the `<head>` tag instead of within the body maybe.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
 animation: "slide"
  });
});
</script>
```

Also, make sure you have a `<script>` tag which loads up jQuery and you also have the .js file for the flexslider defined and loaded, as well as the .css file for the flexslider loaded, preferrably in the head, before you call upon the above code.

Be sure that you have jQuery loaded...  The example uses this for jQuery, so I suggest you use the same:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Put that in your head tag, above the code that initializes the flexslider.

So, between these 2 tags `<head>` and `</head>` you should have something like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path to jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path to flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
     animation: "slide"
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried but it didn't worked. Maybe it has something to do with the foundation jquery that i'm calling.

Comment: Now the error console shows this Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'load'

Comment: Put your browser into javascript error reporting mode and check for any errors in js/jQuery.  If errors pop up, that's a good place to start.

Comment: Ok, looks like jQuery isn't being loaded.  You should confirm that jQuery is loaded in your head tag!